# Retrieve checkbox status from firebase

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a database structure like this:
[Firebasedatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg2ZT.jpg)
I want to get the boolean value to fill another checkbox in my listview items.
When I add a new item, I use a checkbox to set the boolean value to "true or false" in firebase. But I want to get the value to fill another checkbox in my listview.
Here is my adapter (It's inside my MainActivity)

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Jobber, ShowDataViewHolder>
            (Jobber.class, R.layout.list_jobber, ShowDataViewHolder.class, myRef) {


        public void populateViewHolder(final ShowDataViewHolder viewHolder, Jobber model, final int position) {

            viewHolder.Image_Title(model.getJobbnavn());







            viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Jobbliste.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Delete this data ?");
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            int selectedItems = position;
                            mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(selectedItems).removeValue();
                            mFirebaseAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedItems);
                            recyclerView.invalidate();
                            onStart();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
                    dialog.show();

                    return false;
                }
            });



        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
}

public class ShowDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private final CheckedTextView image_title;
    private final CheckBox chk;


    public ShowDataViewHolder(final View itemView) {


        super(itemView);


        image_title = (CheckedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image_title);
        chk = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


    }





    private void Image_Title(String title) {
        image_title.setText(title);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution lies with the `valueEventListener()` available in Firebase Database for getting realtime updates from database. 
You need to add the `valueEventListener()` in the list item which you want to modify based on the boolean value in the database.

 You need to modify the `onDataChanged()`callback function in the `valueEventListener()` which gets automatically called upon changes in the database at the particular `DataReference` on which it is called.
`valueEventListener()` gets automatically triggered when the corresponding value (i.e. database reference where it points) in the database changes, after the function is triggered you execute the desired code to set the checkbox as checked by calling function `setChecked()`.
It may look like this `checkboxVariable.setChecked(true)` 

You may read more about `valueEventListener()` which is function available over the class `DatabaseReference`.

[Example from documentation on `valueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-start)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use `valueEventListener()`, I use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Does this make it harder?

Comment: [Check this for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#data-and-error-events)
. You may have look at this description

Comment: Thank you, gonna check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I will probably do something like this to all my data for that node first. it could be useful in some scenario:

```
public class Data
{
   public String jobId;
   public boolean checked;
}
```

And use the following code to retrieve my value

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("MyReference")
            .child( PROFILE_KEY )
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Data data= dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);

                    if (consumer == null)
                    {
                        //data does not exists for the specified key
                    }
                    else if(data.checked)
                    {
                       //data is checked
                    }
                    else {
                        //data not checked
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                   // there was an error
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can I implement this in my Recyclerview Adapter?

Comment: @Alex Yes you can but I usually avoid making Firebase calls in Adapters. You can instead use an event listener in your adapter and make Firebase calls in your activity instead.

Comment: Can you check my code above, and help me a little bit more. Actually what I want is to use a checkbox in my list_item (with my textview) to set the value in firebase.